# How to choose and write a loop for this specific task?

Tags: java, loops

I am pretty new to Java. Sorry if this is a lame question. I have this chunk of code. It is not the whole thing obviously.

```
    char option = scan.next().charAt(0); 

    for (option !='a'||option !='b'||option !='c'||option !='d'||option !='e'||option !='f'||option !='q') {
        System.out.println("Please pick an option from the menu above");
    }

    int lengthOne = stringOne.length(); //Getting the lengths for each string           
    int lengthTwo = stringTwo.length();

    if (option == 'a'|| option == 'A') { //If the user inputs a
        if (lengthOne == lengthTwo) { //If both lengths are equal
            System.out.println("The strings are the same length");
        }
```

Looking for some advice on which loop i should use for this code. The options will be A-F and then Q to quit.

Comment: how about : the one you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop can seem messy for what you are trying to accomplish. I would use a Switch statement inside a 'do while' loop.

If the user input doesn't match a 'case' then it will go to the default.

When a user enters 'q' to quit then `boolean validSelection` turns to `true` and you will exit the 'do while' loop.

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

    boolean validSelection = false;

    do
    {
        System.out.println( "Please pick an option from the menu above" );
        char option = scan.next().charAt( 0 );
        switch( option )
        {
            case 'a':
                break;
            case 'b':
                break;
            case 'c':
                break;
            case 'd':
                break;
            case 'e':
                break;
            case 'f':
                break;
            case 'q':
                validSelection = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println( "Choice invalid." );
                break;
        }
    }
    while( validSelection == false );
}
}
```

Comment: which is exactly the same as when using a while loop. The only difference between while and do-while is that a do-while's condition will only be first checked after the first iteration, meaning it will always run at least once, while on the other hand, might not be executed, if the condition is set to false before execution.   !validSelection is a better way to check validSelection == false, btw

Comment: This actually helped out a lot and made my code make a lot more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a scan inside the loop.

```
char option = scan.next().charAt(0); 

while (option !='a'||option !='b'||option !='c'||option !='d'||option !='e'||option !='f'||option !='q') {
    System.out.println("Please pick an option from the menu above");
    option = scan.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    char option = scan.next().charAt(0); 

    while (option != 'a' && option !='b' && option != 'c'&& option !='d'&& option !='e'&& option !='f'&& option !='q') {
        System.out.println("Please pick an option from the menu above");
        option = scan.next().charAt(0);
    }
```

You will need the ANDs instead of the ORs or it wont work

Comment: You can also change statement in `while` for something like this: `"abcdefq".indexOf(option) == -1`

Comment: @R4yY you should be more careful with posting code: your while loop won't compile, your logical AND's have to be seperated from the variable name

Comment: Worked fine for me, i tested it. Maybe it was just the pasting, im sry then.